# How to use placeholders with CONVERT in SQL?

Tags: javascript, sql

So here is my code:

```
const result = await connection.query("INSERT INTO myTable ([ID],[ClassId],[Active],
[LastUpdateDateTime],[LastUpdateUser],[Number],[ExternalId],
[MaterialDefinitionId],[CompanyId],[IsBlanket],[Type],[Subtype],
[CreatedDate],[ValidFromDate],[ValidToDate],[OrderedQuantity],
[DeliveredQuantity],[ReservedQuantity],[UnitOfMeasurement],[Status],[Note])

VALUES (?,?,?,CONVERT(DATETIME, ? , 102),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
?,CONVERT(DATETIME, ? , 102),CONVERT(DATETIME, ?, 102),
CONVERT(DATETIME, ? , 102),?,?,?,?,?,?)" , 

['100000061', 'Order' , 1, 
'2020-01-01 11:11:11' , 'xxx' , 123 , '9901177998' , '100000003' ,
'100000012' , 0 , 'xxx', 'xxx', '2020-01-01 11:11:11' , 
'2020-01-01 11:11:11' , '2020-01-01 11:11:11' , 2000.0 , 
0.0 , 0.0, 'xxx' , 'Created' , 'xxx']);
```

I'm trying as you can see to do an insertion of time but i get this Error:
**RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '?'.**

Does anybody know the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: What database do you use ? Also, what valuse do you send instead  of "?" and "?"

Comment: MSSQL, 
first "?" is an integer 1 and second "?" is '2020-01-01' but it has to be replaced in CONVERT(DATETIME, ? , 102))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an array for the parameters in the `connection.query` function to set the values. You're probably only setting the first one in your case.

Check: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-nodejs/insert/

It should look something like this:

```
let stmt = `INSERT INTO todos(title,completed)
            VALUES(?,?)`;
let todo = ['Insert a new row with placeholders', false];

// execute the insert statment
connection.query(stmt, todo, (err, results, fields) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err.message);
  }
  // get inserted id
  console.log('Todo Id:' + results.insertId);
});
```

In your case you should try:

```
const result = await connection.query("INSERT INTO myTable ([ID],[LastUpdateDateTime]) VALUES (? , CONVERT(DATETIME, ? , 102))", [1, '2020-01-01']);
```

Comment: This isn't helping since what i'm trying to do is: replace the "?" in CONVERT(DATETIME, ? , 102) with '2020-01-01'. But it's not working..

Comment: @Pable CG Well i have tried your solution and still getting the same errorr.. check the Update! :/

Comment: if you're using MSSQL you shouldn't use "?" but @ params. Check: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-ver15